# How to count number of rows dropped in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

How do I print the  number of rows dropped while executing the following code in python:

```
df.dropna(inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# making new data frame with dropped NA values
new_data = data.dropna(axis = 0, how ='any')  

len(new_data)
```

Comment: Please add explanations to your code. Code only is not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
np.random.seed(2022) 
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0,np.nan, 1], size=(10, 3)))
print (df)
     0    1    2
0  NaN  0.0  NaN
1  0.0  NaN  NaN
2  0.0  0.0  1.0
3  0.0  0.0  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  1.0
5  1.0  0.0  0.0
6  1.0  0.0  1.0
7  NaN  0.0  1.0
8  1.0  1.0  NaN
9  1.0  0.0  NaN
```

You can count missing values before by [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and `sum`:

```
count = df.isna().any(axis=1).sum()
df.dropna(inplace = True)
print (df)
     0    1    2
2  0.0  0.0  1.0
5  1.0  0.0  0.0
6  1.0  0.0  1.0

print (count)
7
```

Or get difference of size Dataframe before and after `dropna`:

```
orig = df.shape[0]
df.dropna(inplace = True)
count = orig - df.shape[0]
print (df)
     0    1    2
2  0.0  0.0  1.0
5  1.0  0.0  0.0
6  1.0  0.0  1.0

print (count)
7
```

Comment: @aseb I see another wrong answer was accepted, it was accident?